# How to use DELETE on custom route when using json-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, server, json-server

I'm having a couple of issues when calling DELETE on some custom endpoints defined in my routes.json

I have some data that looks like this -

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "creation_time": "2018-06-07 15:56:01",
      "description": "Test App",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Test",
      "update_time": "2018-06-07 15:56:01"
    },
  ],
  "account_types": [
    {
      "app": {
        "description": "Test app",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Test",
        "user_id": "337"
      },
      "creation_time": "2018-06-07 16:00:31",
      "description": "Regular Test account type",
      "id": "2",
      "max": "None",
      "name": "BASIC",
      "update_time": "2018-06-07 16:00:31"
    },
    {
      "app": {
        "description": "Test app",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Test",
        "user_id": "337"
      },
      "creation_time": "2018-08-02 13:48:45",
      "description": "Premium Test account type",
      "id": "8",
      "max": "None",
      "name": "PREMIUM",
      "update_time": "2018-08-02 13:48:45"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my routes.json

```
{
    "/test/:app_id/accounts/type": "/account_types?app.id=:app_id",
    "/test/:app_id/accounts/type/:type_id": "/account_types?app.id=:app_id&id=:type_id"
}
```

This is the output

```
  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading mock-data/apps.json
  Loading routes.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/apps
  http://localhost:3000/account_types

  Other routes
  /test/:app_id/accounts/type -> /account_types?app.id=:app_id
  /test/:app_id/accounts/type/:type_id -> /account_types?app.id=:app_id&id=:type_id

  Home
  http://localhost:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...

GET /account_types?app.id=2&id=2 200 85.703 ms - 334
GET /account_types?app.id=2&id=4 200 81.023 ms - 2
GET /account_types?app.id=2&id=8 200 38.714 ms - 336
DELETE /account_types?app.id=2&id=8 404 26.290 ms - 2
```

This is how I run json-sever

```
json-server --watch mock-data/apps.json -r routes.json
```

When I call GET on these two endpoints, I retrieve the correct info but when I call DELETE on them I receive status code 404, is there something I am doing wrong or is this a known issue?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

TLDR;
I just checked the code of json-server (0.17.0).
The DELETE function only works with **id**,

which you can override using **--id** commandline argument - but this only works for the whole file and not per collection in that file.

I submitted a feature request (not comming soon I guess).

https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1377#issue-1438817936